# Is it better to write react components first as one HTML file then turning them into components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wonder if writing react components as HTML first can be a good idea to plan the project or it is actually a bad idea and time consuming??

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to. Components are literally that: functional components with a UI that lets you interact with them. The fact that they render "as html elements" is almost an afterthought: that's just the UI backing to get the user input into the component, and the resultant state shown to the user.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm sorry but I don't understand. The Stack Overflow team said that: "Avoid answering question in comment", "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". Then, please provide this as an answer.

Comment: This question is minutes away from getting closed as being opinion-seeking. I am not writing a full answer. The only _true_ answer is "do whatever you feel is right, and learn from that, after reading the documentation on React".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though, this is primarily opinion based question, the react documentation simply states to follow these rules:

1. Start With A Mock
2. Break The UI Into A Component Hierarchy
3. Build A Static Version in React
4. Identify The Minimal (but complete) Representation Of UI State
5. Identify Where Your State Should Live
6. Add Inverse Data Flow

See [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for more info.

Comment: So, it is acceptable to start by mocking UI by writing in HTML then convert it to components

Comment: Yes, you can. But I would break the mock to UI in a react component directly.

Comment: If you depend UI with other developer, then it will be very good idea to finish the HTML first.